# How can I handle Blocked Users in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, block

I need a help . Can u guide me How can i Show a message to blocked user that his account has been blocked .  i m just rendering him to post page . but i want to show him some message that your account has been blocked or somthing like we do in validation messages . Please guide briefly .

public function login(Request $request)
    {
         $username= $request->username;

```
     $user = User::where('username',$username)->first();
  //  return $user;

   // return $user->id;
    if($user != null){

        $active = Activation::whereUserId($user->id)->first();

        if($active->completed==0){
        return redirect('/posts');
        }
```

Comment: cant we show him error on form page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session). One way to do that:

```
return redirect('posts')->with('error', 'Your account is blocked');
```

And in a view after redirection:

```
@if (session('error'))
    {{ session('error') }}
@endif
```

If you don't want to redirect the user, just pass a variable into the view:

```
return view('login.form', ['notActivated' => $active->completed === 0])
```

And in the view:

```
@if ($notActivated)
    Your account is blocked
@endif
```

Comment: but how can i handle it first time while loading login view . its show error or undefinded variable .

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon I've shown you an example. If you pass it to the view, it will not be undefined.

Comment: bro i m getting u . but its shows error while loading first time page .

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon well, if I understood you correctly, you need this check to be done when you're loading the view for the first time. If not, just do this `@if (!empty($notActivated))`

Comment: i got it bro . i made another view of login ;)

Comment: yes , now thats working fine . today i learn some more from u . thanks alot